# How do I create contingency tables in R?

Tags: r, contingency

I have a large data frame with many variables.
Many are likert scale answers and schools which observations belong to they are logic variables (and can include overlap).

**Example:**

```
Q1 <- c(1,2,2,4,3,5)

Q2 <- c(3,4,3,5,4,5)

A <- c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)

B <- c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE)

df <- data.frame(Q1,Q2, A, B)
```

The output I want is a contingency table :

```
Q1

1 2 3 4 5

A 1 1 0 1 1

B 0 1 0 1 0
```

where I can do a `chi2` test between schools - here `A` and `B`. Nothing I have tried works.

I think there maybe answer in what I have read online but I lack the knowledge to recognize it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dplyr/tidyr`.  We group by 'Q1', get the `sum` of 'A', 'B' columns using `summarise_each`, convert the 'wide' to 'long' format with `gather` and reshape it back to 'wide' with `spread.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Q1) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(sum(.)), A:B) %>% 
  gather(Var, Val,-Q1) %>%
  spread(Q1, Val)

#     Var     1     2     3     4     5
#   (fctr) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) 
# 1      A     1     1     0     1     1
# 2      B     0     1     0     1     0
```

---

A `base R` option is `xtabs` after converting to `long` format

```
 d1 <- data.frame(Q1= rep(Q1,2), Var= rep(names(df)[3:4],
           each=nrow(df)), Val=unlist(df[3:4]))
 xtabs(Val~Var+Q1, d1)
 #      Q1
 #Var 1 2 3 4 5
 # A 1 1 0 1 1
 # B 0 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: Hi, this isn't really a comment, but a question: I can not find tidyr under install packages. I found dplyr there and installed it. I set the cran mirror to New Zealand (not that I think that should matter).

Comment: @SarahR When you do `install.packages('tidyr')` what is the message?  Usually the Cloud mirror should have that.

Comment: I had only looked it up. Typing install.. gave message
Warning message:
package ‘tidyr’ is not available (for R version 3.0.3)
Which I guess answers why I can not find it. 
Your other suggestion works great.

Comment: @SarahR The new R version is R 3.2.2.  Can you update it to the new version and then install.